# Why the subject is eliminated after "if"?- "I will be able to provide meaningful contributions if accepted."

Tags: conditional-constructions

First of all, I want to ask whether the below sentence is correct.

If so, in the next, why the subject is eliminated after "if"?

And finally, is this elimination formal or informal?

> I will be able to provide meaningful contributions if accepted.

Comment: It's a kind of ellipsis, and both the subject and a be-verb are omitted  "if **it is** so" and  "... if **I am** accepted". You might find an answer here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/491192/can-i-omit-a-subject-in-if-clauses

Comment: Dear @JavaLatte thanks. That link works for me. But could you tell me about the formality and informality of the usage?

Comment: Generally speaking, ellipsis is acceptable in formal written English, and may actually be more common than in informal spoken English. For example, informally, you would say "If I get the job." Note that most contractions used in informal speech, for example omission of **that** and shortening **cannot** to **can't**, are not ellipsis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only works if the subject is the same, obviously. You cannot say 'I will be able to do X if George is accepted'... and leave our George :)

So the full sentence reads, "I will be able to provide meaningful contributions if I am accepted" and you can, if you do it right, leave the "I am" out as implied from the earlier part of the sentence.

See a sentence like, "I am going to go to the park, meet up with Sue, and have lunch." Read like that I will be eating lunch alone, so better, "I am going to go tot he park, meet up with Sue, and we'll have lunch." The 'we' comes in in order to make it so we both get lunch :)